# How easy or difficult is it to move a web application to Azure?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I am almost done developing an MVC 4 & EF 5 (.net 4.5). I will need to deploy it on azure. Can I simply deploy it without modifying my code ? OR The application has to be specially developed FOR azure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on if you are going to use the web roles or if you are going to use the Azure hosted sites thing.  If you are going to use the web roles, you will need to add an Azure publishing project that created the XML files for configuring the web role for use (host headers, access keys, OS version etc).

As for your actual code, no, azure is just a hosted instance of IIS (for the most part) and any typical application should run without issue.  However, if you are planning on using SQL Azure, there are some differences between that and stand alone SQL that you will need to address.

There are plenty of resources on MSDN concerning azure hosting and migration by the way, here are a few to help you get started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn194221.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn194225.aspx